# Is this sentence trying to invoke a submethod?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, variables, subclass

I have a Python unittest with which I have to create its classes and their methods.
In this unittest there's a sentence with the follow syntax:

```
object.method().something
```

What does this "something" refer to? Does it have to be a submethod of the method() or does it have to be a variable of the method()? Or maybe it's a mistake?

Comment: A "submethod" isn't a thing. `object.method().something` is accessing the `something` attribute of whatever `object.method()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Like it can be

```
a.lower().rstrip()
```

This is simple example that I can quote. Here 'a' is the object of class 'str' and lower() is the method of class 'str'. And that something is rstrip()

Comment: Importantly here what `a.lower()` returns is *also* an instance of `str`.